TV Series for kids, Don't be afraid, The Sandman is here
I'm looking for an old TV show, probably 1990s or earlier.
It's a mix of live actors and cartoons.
A typical episode goes as follows:
We look in at a family, a character, and we explore the flaws in personality. Disobedience, rudeness, eats too much junkfood (yes, it's that kind), etc.
As soon as the character falls asleep, the cartoon starts.
There, the character (usually a kid), is dropped into a dream-world. In the case of the kid who won't eat anything but junkfood, he befriends one of the vegetables, but a war breaks out between vegetables and junkfood, and his friend is seriously injured.
There's this song that plays, with flutes, iirc.
The last line of the song is:
"Don't be afraid, the sandman is here..."

Do you know the country of origin?

@Walt, I'm afraid not.

I can't say I've ever seen this show before, but Google has provided a possible answer:
Nilus the Sandman

Nilus the Sandman was a Canadian part-animated and part-live action television series that originally aired on 1996 on the Family Channel (now Family). The series was produced by Western International Communications (WIC).
The show features a sandman, Nilus (voiced by Long John Baldry), who helps children and teenagers through their dreams while they are asleep, with the dream stories being animated. The parts at the beginning and the end of the series are shot in live action in Vancouver, British Columbia. 26 episode

Here's a video clip of the opening.
Lyrics:

"Hush now child, I'm a friend of yours,
  There is no reason to fear!
  just touch my hand and you'll understand
  you'll know the sandman's here
  I'll guide you through this wonderous night
  Protect you from nightmares you fear
  and if some sights should cause you fright
  you can be sure the sandman's near."  


I think that's the closest, thanks. I'll look into it.
